# Why do bash variable assignments affect the last exit code $? and where is this documented?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, exit-status

I was surprised to find out that setting an environment variable modified the last exist code variable `$?`:

```
$ false
$ echo $?
1
$ false
$ FOO=BAR
$ echo $?
0
$
```

The bash manual says only this about `$?`:

> ($?) Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed
>   foreground pipeline.

**Where is the exit code of a variable being set documented?** Can it fail?

Comment: FOO=$(BAR) it failed

Comment: @IporSircer I tried that and you're right. It returned `127`. However, is that the return code from "setting the variable" or from attempting to run a command that doesn't exist?

Comment: Also `empty= a=${empty:?}`

Comment: @Steve Yes that `127` is from the command not being found. I don't know where this was documented but this - the result of the command inside the substitution being transparently passed through variable assignment - *is* universal behavior that you can rely on, and any new shell that fails to implement this behavior while aiming to be Bourne-like/compatible is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Assignment can fail if the right hand expression fails to evaluate

eg

```
$ x=HELLO
$ x=$((1/0))
bash: 1/0: division by 0 (error token is "0")
$ echo $?
1
```

In this scenario the value of `$x` is left unchanged:

```
$ echo $x
HELLO
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: Hmm, not sure where this is documented, but the return code from a variable assignment is the return code of the evaluation of the right hand side.  That's why `x=$(Nosuchcommand)` returns an exit code of 127 because that's the standard "command not found" exit code.

Comment: `man bash` and search for `EXIT STATUS`.  Is this the location that is being sought?

Comment: @TimothyMartin Not sure ... the man page talks about "commands" and "built-in commands", but that's where I'm confused. I never would have thought setting a variable was a "command" (although something like `$(command)` is obviously a command).

Comment: It's not entirely accurate, but I like to think of an assignment statement as a pre-command assignment that just happens to precede a null command that behaves like `:`. The assignments affect the current shell just like redirections on `exec` with no arguments affect the current shell.

Comment: @chepner It's not like preceding "a null command that behaves like `:`"! Note the difference between `v=$(false)` and `v=$(false) :`. (Note, however, that the same trick does *not* suppress the error status from bad arithmetic expansion: `v=$((1/0)) :` still errors out.
)